# mysql best index order for (FK, key, value)

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a key value table:

```
id, data_id, key, value
```

that references a data table:

```
id, file_id, data
```

which in turn references a files table:

```
id, name
```

files contains about 10000 entries
data contains about 100 million entries

The key column has about 100 distinct values
The value field has many distinct values (strings)

Now I am wondering which order the three columns `data_id, key, value`
should have in my index.

The queries that I am interested in look for data entries that have certain file_id and specific key value combinations. E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM files, data, keyval
WHERE files.id = data.file_id
AND data.id = keyval.data_id
AND files.id = 999
AND keyval.key = 'revenue'
AND keyval.val = 9.99
```

Comment: Note to whoever voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based".... if we are choosing which indexes to define based on "opinion", we are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The "best order" of the columns in an index will depend on the actual query (queries) that are accessing the table.

If the only predicate in the queries we run are `WHERE data.key = 'foo'`, then the  most benefit would be with an index that has `key` as the leading column.

If we don't ever have any queries that have a predicate on the `key` column (in a WHERE clause or an ON clause), and no queries do a `GROUP BY data.key, ...`, then we probably don't need to have `key` as the leading column in any index.

Sometimes we add multiple indexes, with different sets and orders of columns, in order to satisfy a variety of queries.

The choice of order of columns in an index depends not only on the datatypes and  value distribution, but also on the performance requirements for the actual queries that we are planning to run.

---

**EDIT**

The query added to the question is of the form:

```
 SELECT f.*
      , d.*
      , k.*
   FROM files f
   JOIN data d
     ON d.file_id = f.id
   JOIN keyval k
     ON k.data_id = d.id
    AND k.key     = 'revenue'
    AND k.val     = 9.99
  WHERE f.id = 999
```

Assuming

`id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in `files`, and

`id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in `data`

I'd create indexes

```
 ON data (file_id,id)
 ON keyval (data_id,key,val)
```

I'd look at the EXPLAIN output for the query to see the query plan, and which indexes are being used.

---

If we didn't have the equality prediate on `file.id`, and if `key='revenue' and val=9.99` is *very* selective, 
then we would probably want `keyval` as the driving table. And we would make sure an index avaiable that has 
`key` and `val` as the leading columns, e.g.

```
ON keyval(key,val,data_id)
```

We would want that index if the query was equivalent to:

```
 SELECT f.*
      , d.*
      , k.*
   FROM keyval k
   JOIN data
     ON d.id  = k.data_id
   JOIN files f
     ON f.id  = d.file_id
 -- AND f.id  = 999
  WHERE k.key = 'revenue'
    AND k.val = 9.99
```

Also, do we really need to pull *all* of the columns from *all* three tables? 
Or are we just using `*` as a shortcut just to avoid us listing the columns we actually need?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a sample query. I have updated the question to illustrate the index requirements more clearly

Answer (score 0):

A key-value schema sucks.  As your queries get more involved, you will understand why.

One thing you can do to help *some* is to follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Also, please specify the relationships in the tables via `JOIN ... ON`, not the old fashioned `FROM a,b WHERE a.x = b.y`